# Can't pass Android custom meta-data in Titanium app

Tags: javascript, android, xml, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have a requirement where I need to add custom meta-data to an Android app for it to be run on a device.

I created the following file: `platform/android/AndroidManifest.xml`

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.bizname.androidtest">
    <application>
        <meta-data android:name="application-type" android:value="vaa_merchant"/>
    </application>
</manifest>`

The meta-data in this example only makes it into the .apk file because it is within the `<application>` tag. However if I move it outside of the `<application>` tag which is my requirement the `<meta-data>` tag is stripped out during the build process.

My question is how do I keep the `<meta-data>` from being stripped out during the build process?

Titanium SDK version 5.1.2.v20151216190036

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my understanding on Android meta-data is not supposed to be outside application tag. It can be inside activity,activity-alias,service,receiver,provider or application tag. According to the placement its accessibility is defined. If it is outside application tag it has no use.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I think you might be right. It's a requirement for a vendor we are working with but I believe it should be done as you have stated. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed. And I'd suggest you add additional manifest information via [tiapp.xml](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/tiapp.xml_and_timodule.xml_Reference-section-29004921_tiapp.xmlandtimodule.xmlReference-manifest) instead of a custom `AndroidManifest.xml` as it is easier to maintain that way.